# How to change device orientation when app returns to foreground in iOS?

Tags: ios, screen, orientation, screen-orientation

i have change the orientation from portrait to landscape in sub view controller using the below code

```
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber      numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

but when I go to background and return to foreground, then I press button to go to the home page then need change orientation from landscape to portrait using the below code

```
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber      numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if ([ConfigObjC currentPage] && [[ConfigObjC currentPage] isEqualToString:@"SubViewController"])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
    }
    else{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

but it not work.

i have successful to change orienration from landscape to portrait when i no go to background. how can i fix this problem thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to place your windows in landscape mode, you can modify Xcode info to support landscape only,like this:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Another way by coding is to change orientation of `UIWindow`, like this:

```
UIApplication *application=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
[application setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
application.keyWindow.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
```

Using this way above needs to set `ShouldAutoRotate` with `NO`.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
}
```

Besides, if there are only several views displaying in landscape mode , you can use the property `transform` to rotate these views, like this:

```
//rotate screen only with view
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```

Hope can help you!

Comment: i have do the orientation using the below code     NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];, but when I go to background and return to foreground, then I try to change orienttation to Portrait using    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"]; it not work

Comment: UIDeviceOrientation is readonly and UIInterfaceOrientation is readwrite. You can register notification with UIDeviceOrientation and then rotate you screen as well as view